# Fourier transform not working!

Tags: fourier-analysis

The `FourierTransform` doesn't seem to work on the following function:

```
    fun[x_, y_, t_] = 
  1/((x - 4 y) (x + 4 y) (x^2 + 2 y^2))
    E^(-(1/4)
      t (3 x + Sqrt[
      x^2 - 16 y^2])) (-E^(1/4 t (3 x + Sqrt[x^2 - 16 y^2]))
        x^2 (x - 4 y) (x + 4 y) + x^3 Sqrt[x^2 - 16 y^2] - 
     E^(1/2 t Sqrt[x^2 - 16 y^2]) x^3 Sqrt[x^2 - 16 y^2] + 
     5 x y^2 Sqrt[x^2 - 16 y^2] - 
     5 E^(1/2 t Sqrt[x^2 - 16 y^2]) x y^2 Sqrt[
      x^2 - 16 y^2] + (1 + E^(1/2 t Sqrt[x^2 - 16 y^2])) (x - 
        4 y) (x + 4 y) (x^2 + y^2));
```

Doing `FourierTransform[fun[x, y, t], t, \[Omega]]` simply returns the same thing (i.e., FourierTransform[expression of the function]. How can I calculate the FourierTransform of this function and plot it?

Comment: Using `Expand` beforehand might work.

Comment: Thanks @JulienKluge, it did give an expression. But I am not able to plot it with respect to $\omega$!

Comment: To plot it, you will need to assign numerical values to `x` and `y`.  If its imaginary part is non-zero, you will need to convert it to real numbers (e.g. using `Abs`, `Re`, `Im` or `ReIm`)

Comment: I tried that in the first place. The problem seems to come from the DiracDelta in the expression of FourierTransform.

Comment: I think for most of values of `x` and `y` that `FourierTransform` simply does not exist. For example, putting `{x -> 1, y -> 1}]`, we otain a meaningless result `-8 I Sqrt[(2 \[Pi])/15] DiracDelta[-3 I + Sqrt[15] - 4 s] + 
 8/3 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] DiracDelta[-3 I + Sqrt[15] - 4 s] - 
 1/3 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] DiracDelta[s] + 
 8 I Sqrt[(2 \[Pi])/15] DiracDelta[3 I + Sqrt[15] + 4 s] + 
 8/3 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] DiracDelta[3 I + Sqrt[15] + 4 s]`. Here `s` instead of `\[Omega]` is used. Putting `{x -> 5, y -> 1}`, one obtains `-(25/27) + 76/27 E^(-9 t/2) - (8 E^(-3 t))/9`. Its FT does not exist.